# Does an irreducible quaternionic type representation over $\mathbb{R}$ have a ``good'' matrix expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, quaternions

Let $V$ be a real vector space and $G$ be a finite group and $\rho:G \rightarrow GL(V)$ be an irreducible representation over $\mathbb{R}$.
It is of quaternionic type if $\text{Hom}_G(\rho,\rho)$, the set of commuting linear maps, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.
Is there a representation $\rho'$ equivalent to $\rho$ whose matrix expression is in $H_k$ for some $k$?

Here $H_k$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{4k \times 4k}$ whose each $4 \times 4$ subblock is of the form 
\begin{pmatrix}
 a&-b &-c &-d \\
 b&a &-d &c \\
 c&d &a &-b \\
 d&-c &b &a \\
\end{pmatrix}
for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.

Motivation:

I am interested in the real irreducile representation and wish to prove similar result to Schur orthogonality relation.
(I.e. counterpart to ``coordinates statement'' part of
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations
)

For quaternionic type irreducible representation, if the answer to my question is yes, I think I can prove the orthogonlaity.

Comment: I think so. Pick three elements $I, J, K \in \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{R} G}(V)$ which satisfy the quaternion relations $I^2 = J^2 = K^2 = IJK = -\operatorname{id}_V$, this makes $V$ into an $\mathbb{H}$-vector space. You can start generating $\mathbb{H}$-bases of $V$ by picking a nonzero vector $v$, and placing $(v, Iv, Jv, Kv)$ into your basis, then pick a nonzero vector in a complement and keep going.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Then, as I mentioned in Motivation, I think the orthogonality relation similar to Schur orthogonality holds.
Is this orthogonality of real irreducible representation well-know?